# font size and hide property for categorybuttons items in delphi

Tags: delphi, button, fonts, hide, categories

Category Buttons component hasn't font property for each categories and items separately. It also hasn't show hide properties for them. Now how can I hack Category Buttons component to do that something like the following codes :

```
  CategoryButtons1.Categories[1].Items[1].Font.Size := 12;
  CategoryButtons1.Categories[1].Font.Size := 12;
  CategoryButtons1.Categories[1].Items[1].Hide;
  CategoryButtons1.Categories[1].Hide;
  CategoryButtons1.Categories[1].Items[1].Show;
  CategoryButtons1.Categories[1].Show;
```

Thank you

Comment: Read the source code, and go to work. Probably not going to be easy. Not sure the question is a good fit here.

Comment: The above code is not the real code and i wrote that for better imaging...

Comment: No, I do understand that this is the code that you would like to be able to write. But you can't. So you need to either find a different component that meets your needs, or hack this one. It's a bit much to ask us to hack away at an Embarcadero control whose source we do not control. Perhaps you should instead just submit a feature request. In any case this question is a poor fit here, way too broad.

Comment: You cannot hack into `TCategoryButtons` because there is nothing to hack. You would need to completely rewrite half of the code to achieve what you want.

Comment: Sorry to say, but I spoke too soon and I must remove my answer. I had a misunderstanding of the internal structures. As both David H. and Dalija P. said, to modify the control to allow for your requests is not really feasible. You may want to remove the upvote, so I leave the answer visible for a couple of hours.

Comment: Your saying is right thank you from all of you for trying to answer my question